# How to get data with relationship in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, relationship

I'm new to Neo4j and come from PostgreSQL. So, I'm facing a problem with retrieving a set of data in a relationship. For more detail, I have Category and Product Nodes. So, I would like to retrieve data like the following:

```
[{
   name: category_1,
   products: [],
 },
 {  name: category_2,
   products: []
}]
```

It's easy for me if I do it in PostgreSQL, but in Neo4j I don't know how to do that.
The relationship between category and product is one-to-many.
Thanks for any supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best approach would be to use the ˙collect` clause twice:

```
MATCH (c:Category)-->(p:Product)
WITH {name:c.name, products: collect(p.name)} as single_product
RETURN collect(single_product) as result
```